# Is there an API that provides information on the consensus algorithm of altcoins?

Tags: api, consensus

Is there an API that offers information on the consensus algorithm of altcoins? Something like examplewebsite.org/api?name=steem

`{
...
"consensus":"DPoS",
...
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API from [CryptoCompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/) will give you the consensus algorithm under the key `proofType`.